# How can I show response of aspx.cs file in particular html tag in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

As you can see here the addition of two numbers is showing on the top of the page but I want to show the addition of two numbers in the table tag - how can I do that? How can I show result of two numbers in the table tag? What should I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table id="tbl1" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Enter the Number1:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Enter the Number2:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                         <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
         
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System. Linq;
using System. Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System. Web. UI.WebControls;

namespace sample1
{
    public partial class First: System.Web. UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int no1 = Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text);
            int no2 = Convert.ToInt32(textbox2.Text);
            int c = no1 + no2;
            Response.Write(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways. Most easy is to drop in a control - with server side tag.

So, lets put the total into a Textbox3, and ALSO say into a "h3" tag.

so, this markup:

```
        <div style="text-align:center">

            <div style="width: 25em; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
                <div style="text-align: right">
                    Enter the Number 1: 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    Enter the Number 2:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <div style="border-top: 3px solid; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 8px"></div>

                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Button2_Click"
                        Style="margin-right: 25px" CssClass="btn" />
                    Total:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <h3 id="MyH3" runat="server"></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this code behind:

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int MyTotal = 0;
        MyTotal = Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textbox2.Text);
        textbox3.Text = MyTotal.ToString();
        MyH3.InnerText = MyTotal.ToString();
    }
```

Output:

[image]

So, as a general rule, just add a "id" and a runat = server to the tag in question. It can then be used in code behind - even with inteli-sense.